# How do I revert a button color?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to write plain JS code to implement a multiple choice question. I have been able to get the button colors to change to red or green depending on if the correct answer is selected, however I want to make sure that when a separate answer is clicked the remaining buttons revert back to their original color. I am trying to do this with a for loop. There doesn't seem to be errors in the code as per dev tools but the red buttons just stay red when the correct answer is clicked after. Where am I going wrong here?

```js
<!-- revert button colors (#d9edff) using the variables unclicked and doc query selector-->
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  let correct = document.querySelector(".correct_answer");
  correct.addEventListener('click', function() {
    correct.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    let correct_feedback = document.querySelector(".feedback");
    correct_feedback.innerText = 'Correct!';
    let unclicked = document.querySelectorAll(".incorrect_answer");
    for (let i = 0; i < unclicked.length; i++){
      unclicked.style.backgroundColor = '#d9edff';
      }
    });
  let incorrects = document.querySelectorAll(".incorrect_answer");
  incorrects.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    let clicked = event.srcElement;
    clicked.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    let incorrect_feedback = document.querySelector(".feedback");
      incorrect_feedback.innerText = 'Incorrect';
  }));
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Trivia!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Trivia!</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="section">
        <h2>Part 1: Multiple Choice </h2>
        <hr>
        <h3>How many species of Dolphin are there?</h3>
          <button class="correct_answer">42</button>
          <button class="incorrect_answer">53</button>
          <button class="incorrect_answer">24</button>
          <button class="incorrect_answer">11</button>
          <p class="feedback"></p>
      </div>
```

Comment: validating user input (e.g.: checking for right/wrong answer) should be done on server side (e.g.: php/node/python) instead of on client side (e.g.: javascript), to prevent users from using inspect element or view source to see the correct answer

Comment: two issues ... you look for `.incorrects` .... nothing has that class, so what do you expect. If it did find elements, then `unclicked` is a *nodeList*, so `unclicked.style.backgroundColor` would throw an error

Comment: Thanks Kristian, I will keep that in mind for sure! This isn't something that I am going to release, more of a practice project to understand the basics of JS for me as it's the first time I have written anything in it.

Comment: @JaromandaX I see. I have adjusted and it does throw an error: index.html:18 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'backgroundColor').
Why do I get this error with this list and not with the other lists I create when I use similar syntax e.g.  let correct = document.querySelector(".correct_answer"); ?

Comment: so ... you have that in a for loop ... can you guess what the fix is? hint - a `NodeList` is a bit like an `Array`

Comment: @JaromandaX Thank you! That hint was very helpful, though I feel like a fool now that the solution is so simple.
Truly appreciate the help :)

Comment: better that you figured it out for yourself though :p

Comment: @Shanahando You can take a look at this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-firefly-ygfzqx?file=/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  let unclicked = document.querySelectorAll(".incorrects");
```

are you sure you want this? Not ".incorrect_answer" ?

Comment: Completely missed this, thanks for pointing that out! I have changed that now and I'm getting uncaught typeerrors

Comment: @Shanahando  unclicked[i].style.backgroundColor = '#d9edff';

"unclicked" is an array of nodes. You created a for loop to go through all of them, but you need to use the "i" to get the index of each node inside of "unclicked"

Comment: Thanks! I realized that from Jaromandas comment above. So simple. Will mark that as the answer though, thanks!

Comment: basically you can use onclick function and when another button is clicked you want to change the targeted button color and other button should remain in its original color . there are more ways to do it . like onclick with onblur . or onmouseup and onmousedown .

Answer (score 1):

**never lose hope doing something .your code is a bit complex for this question .  i choosed onclick and onblur events without any loop. but your complexing code will definitely make you a more powerful logic builder.you will be more strong if you will be doing this same thing using onmouseup onmousedown events . it will give you more confidence more than you think . we are always there to help you . never lose hope !!**

```js
let change1=(event)=>{
    event.target.style.backgroundColor="green"
}
let change2=(event)=>{
    event.target.style.backgroundColor="red"
}
let blur2=(event)=>{
    event.target.style.backgroundColor="white"
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <h1>Trivia!</h1>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="section">
        <h2>Part 1: Multiple Choice </h2>
        <hr>
        <h3>How many species of Dolphin are there?</h3>
            <button id="correct_answer" onclick="change1(event)" onblur="blur2(event)">42</button>
            <button class="incorrect_answer" onclick="change2(event)" onblur="blur2(event)">53</button>
            <button class="incorrect_answer" onclick="change2(event)" onblur="blur2(event)">24</button>
            <button class="incorrect_answer" onclick="change2(event)" onblur="blur2(event)">11</button>
            <p class="feedback"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Really appreciate the encouragement and how you have showed me a more simple method. Needed those words! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

here is a better way to achieve your task

rather than using update background-color direct from javascript, we can use the CSS class

```
<style>
  button.selected.correct_answer {
    background-color: green;
  }

  button.selected.incorrect_answer {
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>
```

your javascript to add and remove CSS class on button click

```
<script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
          let feedBack = document.querySelector(".feedback");
          let options = document.querySelectorAll(".correct_answer,.incorrect_answer");
          options.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            
            // get all button which has selected on it 
            let selectedOption = document.querySelectorAll(".selected")[0];
            if (selectedOption !== undefined) {
              // remove the selected class from the button So its will revert to its original color 
              selectedOption.classList.remove("selected");
            }

            let clicked = this;
            // add selected class on clicked button
            clicked.classList.add('selected');
 
            // identify clicked button by checking CSS class on it 
            if (clicked.classList.contains("correct_answer")) {
              feedBack.innerText = "Correct!";
            } else {
              feedBack.innerText = "Incorrect!";
            }
          }));
        });
</script>
```

your HTML file will look like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Trivia!</title>

    <style>
      button.selected.correct_answer {
        background-color: green;
      }

      button.selected.incorrect_answer {
        background-color: red;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Trivia!</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="section">
        <h2>Part 1: Multiple Choice </h2>
        <hr>
        <h3>How many species of Dolphin are there?</h3>
        <button class=" correct_answer">42</button>
        <button class="incorrect_answer">53</button>
        <button class="incorrect_answer">24</button>
        <button class="incorrect_answer">11</button>
        <p class="feedback"></p>
      </div>
    </div>


  </body>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      let feedBack = document.querySelector(".feedback");
      let options = document.querySelectorAll(".correct_answer,.incorrect_answer");
      options.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

        // get all button which has selected on it 
        let selectedOption = document.querySelectorAll(".selected")[0];
        if (selectedOption !== undefined) {
          // remove selected class from button So its will revert to its original color 
          selectedOption.classList.remove("selected");
        }

        let clicked = this;
        // add selected class on clicked button
        clicked.classList.add('selected');

        // identify clicked button by checking CSS class on it 
        if (clicked.classList.contains("correct_answer")) {
          feedBack.innerText = "Correct!";
        } else {
          feedBack.innerText = "Incorrect!";
        }
      }));
    });

  </script>

</html>
```